# Should the "a" be removed in this sentence or not?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which one of these sentences is grammatically correct?

- I cooperated with this company on **a per-project** basis.
- I cooperated with this company on **a project** basis.
- I cooperated with this company on **project** basis.

Answer (score 1):

The first two sentences are correct. They mean the same thing. The third sentence is incorrect. ***Per-project*** is a *compound adjective*. In sentence 2, ***project*** is being used as an *adjectival noun* or *noun adjunct*. You can read about noun adjuncts here:

http://grammarist.com/grammar/nouns-as-adjectives/

In both sentence 1 and 2, you need the indefinite article ***a*** for the noun ***basis***.